# Prioritize component oninit in the aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I'm wondering is there any technique or pattern that I can use to prioritizing the `oninit` call?

I have main component (`MAIN.cmp`) and within it I have few other components `Child1.cmp`, `Child2.cmp` and `Child2.cmp` so what I want is once the page loads I want the `MAIN.cmp` onInit to load first before it goes to the child.cmp.

How would you go after this? any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly control the order of aura:valueInit for components purely in markup (see the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_lifecycle.htm), it demonstrates that children always init before their parents). If you want to control the order, you could use aura:if to delay rendering the children until the parent is done, or you can dynamically create the components in the parent's init handler.

Comment: I'm interested to know how you do in the `aura:if to delay rendering the children until the parent is done` and I have tried to create a variable in the aura component and set to true in the parent onInit controller but that's not working as expected, still loading the child first then parent.